# Нужна помощь с кодом MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

```
MediaPlayer mysound1;
MediaPlayer mysound2;
MediaPlayer mysound3;
MediaPlayer mysound4;

private List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asa);
    mysound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asa);
    mysound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asa);
    players.add(mysound1);
    players.add(mysound2);
    players.add(mysound3);
    players.add(mysound4);
}

public void sound1(View view) {
    mysound1.start();
}

public void sound2(View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound2.start();

}

public void sound3(View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound3.start();
}

public void sound4(View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound4.start();
}

private void stopAll() {
    for (MediaPlayer player : players) {
        player.pause();
        player.seekTo(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Опять неправильное решение, но попробуйте перед стартом плеера заново его создать: `mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пересоздал. Суть в том, что Apk комплитит, запускает, но при нажатии на кнопки, нет воспроизведения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а какое решение здесь будет правильное? Новый код?

Comment: Я вам в прошлом вопросе писал что я думаю о правильном подходе. А пока что попробуйте не останавливать плеер а ставить на паузу и сбрасывать в начало. Тогда и пересоздавать не надо будет: `mp.pause();
mp.seekTo(0);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а куда эти команды вставлять? в Public void не воспринимает.

Comment: Так я же написал - вместо остановки плеера... Т.е. заменить `player.stop();` на эти две строки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб заменил private void stopAll() {
        for (MediaPlayer player : players) {
            MediaPlayer.pause();
            MediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
Получаю ошибки Error:(60, 24) error: non-static method pause() cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(61, 24) error: non-static method seekTo(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Я вам показал код, методы, которые вызываются на экземплярах класса, в вашем случае это переменная внутри цикла с именем `player`. Вы же пытаетесь несуществующий статический метод плеера вызвать. Вот об этом вам компилятор и говорит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я извиняюсь за потраченное вами время, но я не понял, что мне надо сделать.

Comment: Замените `player.stop();` на `player.pause(); player.seekTo(0);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заменил, запустил приложение. На одном из 4 public void у меня не было stopAll, он воспроизводит звук, остальные кнопки молчат и работают как пауза. То есть проблема не решена.

Comment: Других идей у меня нет(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перезалил код в шапку. На public void sound1, убрал stopAll, то есть звук воспроизводит, на остальных молчание и останавливает воспроизведение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Возможно вы мне расскажете как лучше будет написать новый код ? Мне надо 4 кнопки которые будут воспроизводит заданный мною звук. И главное, что бы при нажатии на другую кнопку, музыка играла не одновременно, а воспроизводился трек с последней нажатой кнопки.